# how to update something in mysql through a variable

Tags: python, mysql

I am currently working on a code in python where I have connected it to mysql.
Now when I want to update something its easy through the update query but when I fetch the data from a website and store that data in a variable and then try to use that variable to update it it doesn't work, what can I do to fix this?
I am attaching the code below to refer.
Please help.

```
    last_traded_price = (live_data['JUBLFOOD']['ltp'])
# fetching the previous price from the database
            mycursor.execute("SELECT price FROM stockprice WHERE ID = 'JUBLFOOD' ")
            myresult = mycursor.fetchone()

            for row in myresult:
                previous_price = row
               

            change = last_traded_price - previous_price
            roundup_change = str(round(change, 2))
            print (roundup_change)

            difference = float(roundup_change) / 100
            percent = 0.2
            if difference >= percent:
                print('GREAT!!')

            sql = "UPDATE stockprice SET price = last_traded_price where name = 'JUBLFOOD' "            
            time.sleep(5)

        conditions()
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: please provide the entire code instead of a screenshot so that it will be easy to help u.

Comment: First, try not to post code as a picture, just paste the part of your code as text here. Second, the problem is because you're not using the variable, your whole query is a string, you did not concat the variable to the string.

Comment: i tried concanating the string but it did not work

Comment: what query do you try to run? What error do you get ? We can't run it, and we can't read in your mind - you have to put all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: if you want to create string with full query then you should use `string formating` or `f-string` to put value in string.  `f" .... {variable] ...."` or `" .... {] ....".format(variable)` . And you have to `execute()` this query because I see query `UPDATE`  but not `execute("UPDATE ...")`. OR you should use query with `?` and `execute(query, values)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `?` in query and `execute` it with arguments.

```
mycursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "UPDATE stockprice SET price = ? WHERE name = 'JUBLFOOD'"            
mycursor.execute(sql, (last_traded_price,))

conn.commit()
```

It has to be tuple `(last_traded_price,)` even if you have only one argument.

It may be good to `commit` query - to informa database that you really want changes.

Comment: Tuple means it cannot change right?

Comment: but over here the value in the variable changes every 3min

Comment: if it change every 3 min then you have to run it again every 3 min.

Comment: I don't know if it has to be `tuple` - maybe it will work also with `list` or even with `dict` (all depends on database and if `query` uses `?` or `%(name)s`). But `tuple` uses little less memory then `list`.

Comment: but i made it work and now i think it will work properly